# HTML - Table Background bleeds through

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables, responsive

I'm using datatables.js with a normal table, nothing fancy at all, see screenshot (and problem):
[image]

**Here's a link to the code:**
http://pastebin.com/LfmHkfS2

HTML:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="responsive all" id="highscore">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="all">
                                    Benutzername
                                </th>
                                <th class="all">
                                    Badges
                                </th>
                                <th class="all">
                                    Kalorien
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr class="user">
                            <td class="username all" data-id="123">
                                Max Mustermann
                            </td>
                            <td class="badges_count">
                                4
                            </td>
                            <td class="calories">
                                200
                            </td>
                        </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#highscore').DataTable({
     bFilter: false,
     bInfo: false,
     bLengthChange: false,
     ordering: false,
     responsive:true,
     responsive: {
        details: false
    }
 });
```

CSS:

```
table {
        width: 670px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #575656;
        border-spacing: 0;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 0 auto;

        @include media ('<=phone') {
           width: 280px;
           margin: 0 auto;
       }
       thead {
           background-color: #ffc107;
           tr {
               font-size: 24px;
               color: white;
               text-transform: uppercase;
               text-align: left;
               height: 75px;
               @include media ('<=phone') {
                   font-size: 12px;
                   height: 40px;
               }
               th {
                   &:first-child {
                       padding-left: 35px;
                       border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                       @include media ('<=phone') {
                           padding-left: 10px;
                       }
                   }
                   &:last-child {
                       border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       .user {
           height: 55px;
           .username {
               padding-left: 35px;
               font-family: $font-arial;
               color: #575656;
               font-size: 24px;
               @include media ('<=phone') {
                   font-size: 12px;
                   padding-left: 10px;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Everything in one, because of the length.

**Description:**
I have a thead in the table which is yellow. As soon as I resize the browser or the viewport, the "borders" appear, on all cells.

I noticed that datatables add a custom width to the tables and/or the cells. As soon as I increase or decrease a few px, the borders seem to disappear.

Anyone had this problem?

Edit:
This "border" seems to be a bleed through from the background of the table. The background is white, as soon as I change it to red, the border is red.

Comment: Check or set the responsive value of DataTable JS : "responsive": true

Comment: it is. See at the pastebin link.

Comment: i tried to reproduce. But in my side everything works nicely. may you should post your html, js and css how you have included it

Comment: "Here's a link to the code" — Don't do that. Put a [mcve] **in the question itself**